# jQuery UI slide jumps to create space then animates

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I'm using the slide animation from jQuery UI to insert a div between two others in a row, but when triggering the animation, what happens is the space needed for the div to slide jump appears without animation and then animation comes in.

**EDIT: JSFiddle issue fixed thanks to the guys below. New JSFiddle is: https://jsfiddle.net/7ryukzd7/3/
But the initial issue remains :-)**

For a reason I don't get, in JSFiddle the div doesn't slide inline but breaks (which doesn't happen in a browser)... Anyway the point is illustrated nonetheless. (**this is now solved**)

My code:

HTML:

```
<div class="bloc cover" style="background-color: blue;"><p class="readmore_button">Read More</p></div>
<div class="bloc hidden" style="background-color: red"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p></div>
<div class="bloc cover" style="background-color: blue;"></div>
<div class="bloc cover" style="background-color: blue;"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.bloc {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.cover {
    width: 100 px;
    height: 100 px;
}
.hidden {
    height: 100 px;
    width: 200 px;
}
```

JS with jQuery UI:

```
$('.hidden').hide();

$('.readmore_button').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parents('.bloc').next('.hidden').toggle("slide", 1000);
});
```

I saw similar issues here: [jQuery UI show using slide animation jumps to full height before animation starts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002479/jquery-ui-show-using-slide-animation-jumps-to-full-height-before-animation-start) but couldn't adapt it to my situation.

Any help would be much appreciated, either on the reason why inline-block breaks with animation in JSFiddle (solved) or on the actual issue :-)

Comment: You can try `.ui-effects-wrapper {
  display: inline-block!important;
}` though I don't know if that's the effect you're going for.

Comment: Thanks! I edited my original post with @Stevangelista's fix. My initial issue remains, though.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how the slide animate behavior implemented via the toggle function works - it only animates the element(s) being targeted, not any & every element around it in the DOM. If you want the `div` elements to the right of the target one to also be animated, you need to code it as such.

Answer (score 0):

@Michael Coker is correct; in the course of animating the `div.hidden`, the slide animation effect applies temporary CSS to the element, which includes a clobbering of your `display:inline-block`.

One option is indeed to override the native jQ-ui style; another is to not rely on inline-block styling for your `div` elements so that the animation does not react that way. One way to do so would be with floated elements:

```
.bloc {
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  vertical-align: top;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 2px /* added to recreate the spacing inline-block elements have */
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7ryukzd7/3/

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I've edited my initial post, now the JSFiddle is fine but my animation issue remains :)